# Fire Monkey Image view area

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I want to create simple 2d racing game on FM, I have track (racing map) bitmap. Image component must show only part of that bitmap depending on car position. Is there any way to define coordinates of bitmap's start point, from which Image will show this bitmap. If Image doesn't support that, what component does? Thanks.

Comment: Considered layering the car image over the track image.

Answer (score 0):

Use a TSubImage. This component is similar to a TImage, but lets you specify a sub-section of the image to be displayed.